# Bug in CS50 Readability pset2

Tags: c, debugging, rounding, cs50, floating-accuracy

My code compiled correctly and I passed every test case **except one**.
The bug occurs in the sentence- "In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.", which expects a Grade 7, but My code outputs grade 8.

Here is the output when check50 is deployed:

handles single sentence with multiple words

expected "Grade 7\n" and not "Grade 8\n"

After printing out the number of letters ( 96) , words (23 ) sentences (1) , index (7.548) and round(index) which is 8 for this particular case, explicitly, I saw that all of the numbers are correct.
But I do not understand how 7.548 can be rounded to 7.

Please help me in Debugging the code, and let me know what I'm missing.
Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(int length , char arr[]);

int count_words(int length , char arr[]);

int count_sentences(int n, char arr[]);

int main (void)
{
    // Getting Input from user
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    // Counting letters
    int  n = strlen(text);

    int letter = count_letters(n, text);
    int word = count_words(n, text);
    int sentence = count_sentences(n, text);
    
    float L = (letter*100)/word;
    float S = (sentence*100)/word;

    int index = round((0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8);

    if (index < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (index > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", index);
    }

}

int count_letters(int length , char arr[])
{
    int letters = 0;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < length ;  i++)
    {

        if (tolower(arr[i]) >= 'a' && tolower(arr[i]) <= 'z' )
        {
            letters++ ;
        }

    }

    return letters;
}

int count_words(int length , char arr[])
{
    int words = 1 ;
    for (int i =0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]== ' ')
        {
            words++;
        }
    }
    return words;
}

int count_sentences(int length, char arr[])
{
    int sentence = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i <length ; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == '.')
        {
           sentence ++;
        }
        else if (arr[i] == '?')
        {
            sentence ++;
        }
        else if ( arr[i] == '!')
        {
            sentence++;
        }
    }
    return sentence;
}`
```

Comment: `float L = (letter*100.0)/word;` same with the next line. Even though you are assigning the value to a float the math is being done with all integers so it truncates.

Comment: Don't post (links to) pictures of text output — show the text output in the question.

Comment: -1 for posting pictures of text. How do you think we could copy&paste the link in your first screenshot where the really useful information is available.

Comment: Thank you @RetiredNinja I understood the issue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  will try to remember next time. This was my first attempt at asking a question, hence the links. I thought I was being informative :') Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry for the inconvenience caused

Comment: You can still edit the question. And besides of the fact that pictures are bad option to show plain text, the link I mentioned normally provides useful information and should go into the question.

Comment: For this question it doesn't matter any more but for further questions you might think about including the link to the CS50 result page. There is more information available which can be usefule for answering your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (change it)

```
float L = (letter / (float) word) * 100;
float S = (sentence / (float) word) * 100;
```

The variable "word" needs to be specified as a float.
I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(int length, char arr[]);
int count_words(int length, char arr[]);
int count_sentences(int n, char arr[]);

int main(void)
{
    // Getting Input from user
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    // Length of text
    int  n = strlen(text);
    
    //Calculating Coleman-Liau index 
    float L = ((float)count_letters(n, text) / (float)count_words(n, text)) * 100;
    float S = ((float)count_sentences(n, text) / (float)count_words(n, text)) * 100;
    
    int index = round((0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8);
    
    // Print Grades
    if (index < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (index > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", index);
    }

}

int count_letters(int length, char arr[])
{
    int letters = 0; // Letter counter 
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ;  i++)
    {

        if (tolower(arr[i]) >= 'a' && tolower(arr[i]) <= 'z')
        {
            letters++ ;
        }

    }

    return letters;
}

int count_words(int length, char arr[])
{
    int words = 1 ; // word counter
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == ' ')
        {
            words++;
        }
    }
    return words;
}

int count_sentences(int length, char arr[])
{
    int sentence = 0; // sentence counter
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == '.' || arr[i] == '?' || arr[i] == '!')
        {
            sentence ++;
        }
    }
    
    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: When an int is divided by an int in C, the result is also an int, with any remainder discarded. In other words, the result will be truncated. You might want to cast your one or more values to float before performing division when calculating L and S!